# Using SQL Server's CONTEXT_INFO for Classic ASP Login Tracking

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, audit

I'm migrating a classic ASP site to ASP.NET MVC.  As part of the migration, we've moved the database from MS Access to SQL Server, and have set up basic trigger-level audit logging on the SQL end of things, for good measure.

What I want to do is track the currently logged in user of the classic ASP site for the purpose of the trigger-level auditing.

For the MVC end of things, I use SQL's `SET CONTEXT_INFO` ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx)) in conjunction with Entity Framework and the "one data context per request" rule, which allows me to set the context info to the currently logged in MVC user's ID.  All's well there.

I'd like to to the same with the classic ASP site, but am unsure how.  Is there a way I can capture the "per request" to set up the `CONTEXT_INFO` such as we can in MVC?  I'm not familiar enough with how the Classic ASP pipeline works to know if this can be done, or if the database connection (implemented as a connection string in an include file and an ADODB connection) will be persisted in the App Pool, which would mean that I don't have a way of doing this.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Relying on ADODB connection in the app pool is not a good idea to begin with. But if this just for casual audit tracing, sure nothing wrong.

Comment: @EmacsUser - the legacy Classic ASP app uses an ADODB connection, which I assume is persisted/pooled in the app pool.  I'm open to other ideas on how to set up connections in vbscript for Classic ASP, but I'm of the impression that options are limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some facts.

- `CONTEXT_INFO` stored in session / batch scope not the connection.

From [Using Session Context Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Session context information enables applications to set binary values
>   of up to 128 bytes that can be referenced in multiple batches, stored
>   procedures, triggers, or user-defined functions operating **on the same
>   session**.

- When you take a connection from the pool, ADO (with a decent, preferably official data provider like SQLOLEDB, SQLNCLI of course) executes `sp_reset_connection` which indicates that connection is being reused.
- Starting from SQL Server 2005 [*](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/126925/sp-reset-connection-need-to-clear-context-info), `sp_reset_connection` resets `CONTEXT_INFO`.

From [System Stored Procedures (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961.aspx)

> The **sp_reset_connection** stored procedure is used by SQL Server to
>   support remote stored procedure calls in a transaction. **This stored
>   procedure also causes Audit Login and Audit Logout events to fire when
>   a connection is reused from a connection pool.**

In conclusion, it's safe to use `CONTEXT_INFO` during an open session.

So the following code is in accordance with `one data context per request` rule as long as you stick with the same connection object reference (`adoCon`) during the request.

```vb
<%
Dim adoCon ' global scope variable
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

adoCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=..."
adoCon.Open 'connection taken from the pool, a session "possibly recycled" started

'CONTEXT_INFO() is definitely NULL right now

adoCon.Execute "SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x01"

'all database operations through the adoCon ...

adoCon.Close 'connection closed, session released
%>
```

Comment: Awesome!  I thought this was a dead question.  I had done a bunch of poking around on my own since the question was asked and thought I could get away with doing it like this but your answer confirms a lot for me and is very helpful.  I'll be digging into this next week, give me a few days to try it out and get you an accepted answer.  Thanks

Comment: @jdl134679 no problem, take your time.